# Link 1 x 6 with Stoppers Part 2739b

Tags: building

Will Link 1 X 6 connect to Liftarm 2 Axle Holes and Pin / Crank (Part 33299)? The Link will be attached to a coke can, that needs to drive a crankshaft.

[image: Technic Steering Link 6L Type 2 2739b]
2739b from Peeron

[image: 3x0.5 Liftarm with Boss and Pin 33299]
33299 from Peeron

Answer (score 1):

The half pins on the ends of the lift arms will fit into the round holes of the steering link, yes, but they will obviously have full rotation within that - it's not a "locking" connection.

The idea with the link is to lock a pair of those arms together so that they pivot in unison.